# OWA signature image not sending

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, outlook-web-access

A user's email signature includes an image under Outlook Web Access.

This image can be viewed when looking at sent items under OWA, however the image is missing when the same email is viewed on a recipient's Outlook 2010 (as shown below).

OWA running from Exchange 2010.

[image]

Comment: Does this happen for all recipients?

Comment: I tried two recipients - an Office 365 account + a Gmail account. Both cannot see the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Charlie your answer put me in the right direction.

I uploaded the company logo to tinypic.com, right-clicked > copied the image, then pasted it into the OWA signature. Copying it from a public-available source may have been the answer.

Comment: Yes, the article I linked as source had that information in it. Considering your question was not specific, I answered why the image wouldn't show. You did not ask how to make it appear. Please be more specific in your future questions.

Answer (score 3):

Here is why the image is not appearing.

> OWA doesn't include the ability to insert images into signatures. This
>   is because inserting an image from the local computer won't do much
>   good when you access OWA from another computer and OWA doesn't have
>   the capability to store it online for you.

This **[source](http://www.slipstick.com/exchange/web-access/add-an-image-to-your-signature-in-owa/)** has a workaround if you want to get this image working.

Comment: I'd give you a vote up but I don't have the rep points yet.